# Confusion with axes differences between surface plot and matrix. (trying to solve Poisson equation)

Tags: matlab

I tried to follow this tutorial: [Numerical solutions to the discrete poisson equation](http://www.cryptosystem.org/archives/2009/09/using-matlab-for-numerical-solutions-to-the-discrete-poisson-equation/) and add boundary conditions, but I could not get the axes right. Then I hacked around with some variables, and it seems to have start working, but I am not 100% certain.

Here is the problem I am solving:

```
u_xx + u_yy = f(x,y), 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1.

u(x,y)=lower(x), if y=0
u(x,y)=upper(x), if y=1
u(x,y)=left(y), if x=0
u(x,y)=right(y), if x=1
```

Solver function is following: (the places that worry me are marked with %WARNING%):

```
function [ hor_padded ] = poisson_solver( f, upper, lower, left, right ,m, n)
%m, n - Number of points (same in x and y direction)

x_a=0;
x_b=1;
y_a=0;
y_b=1;

dx = (x_b-x_a)/m; %dx=dy

x=linspace(x_a,x_b,m);
y=linspace(y_a,y_b,n);

g=zeros(m,n);

for i=1:n,
    for j=1:m,
        %WARNING 1% 
        g(j,i)=-f(x(i),y(j))*dx*dx;

        if j==2
           g(j,i)=g(j,i)+lower(x(i));
        end
        if j==n-1
           g(j,i)=g(j,i)+upper(x(i));
        end
        if i==2
           g(j,i)=g(j,i)+left(y(j));
        end
        if i==n-1
           g(j,i)=g(j,i)+right(y(j));
        end
    end
end

b = reshape(g(2:m-1, 2:n-1),(m-2)*(n-2),1);

A = gallery('poisson',m-2);

U = A\b;

u = reshape(U,m-2,n-2);

upper_part=upper(x(2:m-1)); 
lower_part=lower(x(2:m-1)); 
left_part = left(y');
right_part = right(y');

%WARNING 2%
ver_padded = vertcat(lower_part, u, upper_part);
hor_padded = horzcat(left_part, ver_padded, right_part);

end
```

1. Warning 1)  Matlab seems to mix x and y axes inside matrix. (as described here: [Axis labeling question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116849/axis-labeling-question)). So I changed X and Y directions in the for cycle. Is this correct?
2. Warning 2) I had the upper_part and lower_part the other way around at the beginning, but the boundaries did not meet in the resultant graph. I examined the variables, tried the other way around, and it started working. Is this correct?

My test program is here:

```
clear;

m = 100;
n = 100;

x_a=0;
x_b=1;
y_a=0;
y_b=1;

e=exp(1);
f=@(x,y)(e*x+e*y); 

%Boundary conditions
upper = @(x) (x);
lower = @(x) (3-x);
left = @(y) (3-3*y);
right = @(y) (2-y);

u = poisson_solver(f, upper, lower, left, right, m, n);

x=linspace(x_a,x_b,m);
y=linspace(y_a,y_b,n);

surf(x,y,u);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

And another test case: (everything else is as on the upper example):

```
upper = @(x) (exp(x));
lower = @(x) (cos(x*2*pi));
left = @(y) (cos(y*2*pi));
right = @(y) (exp(y));
```

Names "upper", "lower", "left" and "right" refer to the resultant graph, not the corresponding places in the matrix u in solver function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning 1) Matlab seems to mix x and y axes inside matrix. (as described here: Axis labeling question). So I changed X and Y directions in the for cycle. Is this correct?

Yes, first index into a matrix is the row index, 2nd index is the column index:

```
[ (1,1)  (1,2)  . . .   (1,n);
  (2,1)  (2,2)  . . .   (2,n);
    :      :    .         :
    :      :      .       :
    :      :        .     :
  (m,1)  (m,2)  . . .   (m,n)];
```

> Warning 2) I had the upper_part and lower_part the other way around at the beginning, but the boundaries did not meet in the resultant graph. I examined the variables, tried the other way around, and it started working. Is this correct?

If you define a matrix to be xy-plane, then you have to stick to the definition of the indexing. As you can see in my indexing example, the 'origin' (`(1,1)`) is located at the topleft and the 'y-axis' is pointing 'downward'. So with that in mind, your change of upper and lower is correct.

On a sidenote, you could define everything in a different manner of course, it's just a bunch of numbers arranged and stored in a way you define!

Comment: Thanks. It got clearer now after some thinking and reading Your comment and Matlab surf function help. :-)